# How can I copy an git repository in Xcode to github?

Tags: github, xcode6

Every time a try to use github I get tangled in a series of errors that seem to have no solution and I give up. This time I thought I'd try to get help.

I have a local repository created and managed with Xcode. All the local git functions in Xcode work with no problem. Now I want to put this project on github so others can see it. I logged into github and created a repository. It's this one:

```
lummis/CS193P-2015-Assignment-5
```

I added a .gitignore file but then deleted it again because I thought it was causing an error. I tried adding a readme file but wasn't able to. I got some error that didn't make sense to me so I gave up on that. So at this point the github repository is empty so far as I can tell.

My local repository has many commits and is currently up-to-date. IOW there is nothing to commit. But when I do "Source Code / Push" I get the following error:

> Working copy out of date. Try pulling from the remote to get the
>   latest changes then push again.

So I try to do that in Xcode by doing "Source Control / Pull". But then I get this error:

> "github/master" is not a valid remote branch to pull from. Please
>   choose a different remote branch.

But there is only one branch. There is no other branch (local or remote) to choose. So I'm stuck in a Xcode-github error loop again. I searched for information about this but didn't find anything relevant. I have the Pro Git book and read and understood it at least thru chapter 2. But that doesn't help on interacting with Xcode.

Can anybody say what I need to do? I thought of deleting the remote repository and starting over but apparently there's no way to do that either!

I know lots of people use github so it must work once you know how to use it but it's a big source of frustration for me.

Comment: "I added a .gitignore file but then deleted it again because I thought it was causing an error. I tried adding a readme file but wasn't able to. I got some error that didn't make sense to me so I gave up on that." It would be *much* more helpful if you told us what these errors were.

Comment: "So at this point the github repository is empty so far as I can tell." Your GitHub repository does include two commits: `5f34a32` and `f81fbf6`. It might not contain any *files* in the current revision, but a Git repository is not empty if it contains commits. Assuming these two commits aren't in your local repository you won't be able to push to GitHub unless you *force* the push, which should **never** be done unless you fully understand the implications.

Comment: I know it would be more helpful if I gave the content of the error messages but I don't know what they were exactly and I didn't want to give any misinformation. Those errors occurred before I decided to post here. At the time I expected to be able to get past them on my own. The 2 commits you mention are almost surely adding .gitignore and then removing it. The other error (trying to add a README) wasn't a message it was that I pasted the text into what looked like the text box but nothing happened when I clicked Save (or whatever the wording is on the save button).

Comment: I would try to force push. After all, the repository is useless as it is now and I don't have any other way to possibly make it valid. But I don't see how to force push with Xcode.

Comment: "The other error (trying to add a README) wasn't a message it was that I pasted the text into what looked like the text box but nothing happened when I clicked Save (or whatever the wording is on the save button)." Are you trying to edit files through the GitHub web interface? In this case we will probably decide to force push, but it's something that we shouldn't do lightly. Let's make sure we understand what we're doing before force pushing.

Comment: Yes I was using the web interface for that. If I remember right it said something to the effect that I should add a README so others would know what the project is about (something like that). Click on add file then get a web page with "Commit new file", a title area with "Create README.md, and a big box with prompting text "Add an optional extended description..." I already had an explanatory text file within the project so I copied its content and pasted it into the big box. But the "Commit new file" button didn't do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81583/discussion-between-chris-and-robertl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local repository with "many commits". Let's imagine that we have three:

```
A---B---C
        ^
        master
```

Your remote repository on GitHub also contains commits, but they are different ones from what you have locally, e.g.

```
Y---Z
    ^
    master
```

At least one of these remote commits was created through the GitHub web interface, which creates a new commit each time you use it.

Because the two repositories contain no common history, Git can't figure out how to handle a push from your local repository to the remote one. It will refuse to accept such a push rather than making any remote commits inaccessible, which is what you usually want.

In this case, commits `Y` and `Z` in the remote repository can be discarded. They simply add and then remove a `.gitignore` file, and you want the remote to reflect what you have locally. The solution is to *force push*.

Force pushing should generally be avoided, since it can cause commits to be discarded (like `Y` and `Z` will be in this case) or to have their hashes changed, which causes major problems with shared repositories. In this instance I don't see any danger in force pushing, which can be accomplished with the `-f` or `--force` argument to `git push`.

(There's nothing fundamentally wrong with force pushing, and in some situations it makes perfect sense, but it should be done with care for the reasons listed above.)